# Media-queries not working on Sass project

Tags: html, css, sass, media-queries

I am working on a Sass project and everything worked properly, but media queries are not working.
I tried adding them at the bottom of the document, adding in the chain of labels, having more specificity than the normal chain and nothing is working. Do you know what the problem could it be?

Here is what I did:

Breakpoints:

```
$mobile-breakpoint: 600px;
$laptop-breakpoint: 922px;
```

In this case is applying the media query even when the width is less than 922px:

```
img{
    height: 5vw;
    margin: 3vh 4vh 4.6vh 3vh;
    @media(min-width: $laptop-breakpoint){
        height: 4vw;
    }
}
```

The code after being coverted to CSS:

```
.main-header .header-logo-search a img {
  height: 5vw;
  margin: 3vh 4vh 4.6vh 3vh;
}
@media (min-width: 922px) {
  .main-header .header-logo-search a img {
    height: 4vw;
  }
}
```

In this case, it does not apply the media query:

```
input{
      @include search();
      width: 30vw;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 0 1.5vw;
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      background-color: $snow;
      border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
      @media(max-width: 600px){
      display: none;
}
```

The code after being coverted to CSS:

```
.main-header .header-logo-search form input {
  height: 3.5rem;
  line-height: 3.5rem;
  border: none;
  margin: auto 0;
  width: 30vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 1.5vw;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  background-color: #FFF9FB;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .main-header .header-logo-search form input {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see what the issue is. In your second example snippet (i.e. `input` element), you do have an `@include` statement but are not using the Sass variable anywhere. Otherwise the specified media query still compiles as written. What's the problem here?

Comment: Not sure but try to add `@media screen and (min-width: $value) {}`. Also you are not closing `@media` curly braces in input styling after `display: none`.

Comment: Hi guys! The include is linked to the mixin search(), is working normally. Regarding add the "screen and", already did it, not working either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Without a viewport meta tag, your site will be rendered into the device's default virtual viewport.

Comment: Thank you so much! I received this html and did not check about the meta tag. Now is working!

Comment: @DamianMansilla If Anurag Das answer was correct, click the check mark indicating he solved it